# Loading two React instances on the same page

Tags: reactjs

Let's say i'm creating a React widget and bundle it with Webpack.
Is it safe to integrate it on other sites that may use their own version of React, or do I need to do something (like the good old jQuery.noConflict())?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There should not be any problem at all, you only need to wrap the two apps in the same context if you need to pass data between them.